# Why it doesn't print the "Hello"?

Tags: c, printf

This code compiles without any errors but why it doesn't print the "Hello" after 5?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int number = 5;
    printf("%d",number,"Hello");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Make sure you turn your compiler warnings to the max (and read them). Most modern compilers will complain about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need the `%s` placeholder in addition to the `%d` placeholder. See below:

```
printf( "%d %s", number, "Hello" );
```

... notice that `"Hello"` is a string literal (and hence a `NULL` terminated string), meaning that a `%s` placeholder is required if you wish to pass `"Hello"` as an argument. Since you are using a string literal, I suggest you simply do as follows:

```
printf( "%d Hello", number );
```

**Remark:**

1. The `%d` placeholder is for an integer.
2. The `%s` placeholder is for a string (`NULL` terminated array of characters).

Answer (score 1):

`printf` just prints what the first argument (ie. the format) contains.

```
printf("%d %s", number, "Hello");
```

`%s` format is for strings (`"Hello"` is a *string litteral*).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given your format string a marker to print out your second argument.

Make this line:

```
printf("%d",number,"Hello");
```

This:

```
printf("%d%s",number,"Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `%s` specifier is needed for string. Read about format specifiers [here](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output).
 Change

```
 printf("%d",number,"Hello");
```

to

```
  printf("%d %s",number,"Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` will print only what is specified in the format string. Your format string provides one conversion specifier `"%d"` and the argument `number` that corresponds to it. There is no conversion specifier corresponding to the argument `"Hello"`, so that argument is discarded. To print that one, you'll need another conversion specifier:

```
printf ("%d %s", number, "Hello");
```

or better yet, since it's a string literal anyway:

```
printf ("%d Hello", number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
printf("%d %s", number, "Hello")
```

or

```
printf("%d Hello", number)
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one placeholder in your format string.  Try:

```
printf("%d %s", number, "Hello");
```

This should print:
5 Hello

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%d %s",number,"Hello");
           ^
           Here it is.
```

Answer (score 0):

printf function takes various number of parameter ( ... ) and prints first N parameter (N is number of placeholder). printf function doesn't know the number of parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers clearly have mentioned that you should use `%s` in your `printf()` along with  `%d` , as to know why it doesn't show any error but still doesn't print "hello" you should take following points into consideration :

1. First of all `printf()` is a variadic function i.e, it takes variable number of arguments. Here you provide 3 arguments namely : **"%d"** , **number** and **"hello"** .
2. Most functions take a specific number of arguments, and the compiler can
   check to see whether you've used the correct number. However, `printf()` can have one, two,
   three, or more arguments, and that keeps the compiler from using its usual methods for error
   checking.
3. **It's your job as a programmer to make sure the number of format specifiers (here `%d`) matches the number of values**;
   the compiler won't catch mistakes of that kind. Since there is no matching format specifier for "hello" it won't print it. AS for why, as I said it ain't a syntax error, it doesn't violate C rules and hence , compiler doesn't detect them.

**NOTE-** The `printf()` and `scanf()` functions
use the first argument to indicate how many additional arguments are coming. The trick is that
each format specification in the initial string indicates an additional argument.

**Besides,** Get rid of `conio.h` and `getch()` both are non-standard, If you are using TURBO C just leave it and search for some other compilers.